# Change shape and dtype of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I have a list of numpy arrays, and each one of them has a dtype=object in the first dimension (3 objects), where there are arrays of different shapes e.g.  (200, 10), (100, 10), (50, 10).

Although this works well, when it happens that the three objects get the same first dimension (e.g. (200, 10), (200,10), (200,10)), the array automatically goes from dtype=object to dtype=float). So, i end up with one of these arrays, being (3,200,10), instead of (3,) object type.

That ends up with an error when i try to make the list a numpy array, since one of the arrays has different shape.

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: You can pre-allocate an array of `None`s with `shape = (3,)` and `dtype=object` and assign each element.

Comment: Why do you want to create an `object` array in the first place? In most cases it is not really what you want.

Comment: Can you please post the code of what you create and how you want to use it later so we have a better understanding what is going on?

Comment: I think Yakym's idea is working. I don't "want" to create an object array. This is automatically done, since the 3 arrays have different 1st dimension. But sometimes, by chance, it happens that they have the same, so numpy behaves as it's a full shape (3,x,x). That creates inconsistency in the overall list.

Sorry can't post the code. I gave a simple example of what's going on.

Comment: `numpy` preferentially creates a multidimensional numeric array, and falls back on the `object` dtype when element sizes differ.  The pre-allocation is simplest way of ensuring that the result is desired object dtype and shape.